# nvme device-self-test - no progress for 78 seconds, stop waiting

Tags: linux, debian, smartctl, nvme

The description says it all:

When running a nvme self-test it is not starting at all:

```
nvme device-self-test /dev/nvme0n1 -s 1h -w &&  nvme device-self-test /dev/nvme1n1 -s 1h -w && smartctl -H /dev/nvme0n1 && smartctl -H /dev/nvme1n1
```

This is the command I always use for testing servers with 2 NVMe drives. And 99% of the time it works pefectly fine, but sometimes (for both nvme drives!) I get the message:

```
Short Device self-test started
Waiting for self test completion...
[|                                                 ]   0%no progress for 78 seconds, stop waiting
```

A quick read test shows adequate performance:

```
hdparm -t --direct /dev/nvme?n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 6344 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2114.37 MB/sec

/dev/nvme1n1:
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 6392 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2130.13 MB/sec
```

There are also no AER errors that might indicate an issue with the link (and AER is definitely supported on the hardware)

What could be the issue here?

Comment: My bet is on crummy vendor firmware. The only thing you can hope to do is check for firmware updates using fwupdmgr

Comment: Thx. I thought, this might be the case. I will check on it if I have the possibility again. Not sure when however.